# How can I ensure that my design works for colorblind people?

Tags: color, design-principles, user-experience

How can I ensure that my designs work for colorblind people?
Whether for web or print...
My teachers always said that red and black don't mix well, but how can I know for sure?

Are there do's & dont's? Or tools that I can use?

Comment: Photoshop and illustrator has simulators for more common types in the proofing optins

Answer (score 3):

You can use some simulators.

https://www.google.com/search?q=color+blind+simulator

Make a snapshot of your website and upload it for example on this page: http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would to use colors that the majority of people can see while also designing in a way that makes sense and is correct. Maybe you need to design in one color or black and white. You can also play with tone and value as a way to make your designs more dynamic. There's a lot of different approaches to this method. It's also helpful to get feedback from the colorblind people who may be viewing your designs.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat and Illustrator both have rudimentary colorblindness checkers. I use them for maps and illustrations, and I also open PDFs in Photoshop to check for these issues.
1. Click the "View" tab in the menu bar.
2. In the dropdown menu, hold your mouse over "Proof Setup."
3. Another dropdown menu will open. Select "Color blindness - Protanopia-type" or "Color blindness - Deuteranopia-type," and you will see how your publication looks to anyone who has those issues.

I have also added Grayscale to my Proof Setup , which reveals other contrast issues that might make the publication hard to read. (I work at a public agency and manual contrast checks are a required step testing PDFs for accessibility per §508 of the [federal] Rehabilitation Act of 1973. )

The biggest offender: Bright red lines drawn over aerial photographs serving as maps. People with colorblindness or contrast issues will see faint gray lines.